# Type Mismatch on Recursive Call of Method with Generic Traversable Parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I can make a (silly) `drop` wrapper which accepts some `Traversable` type and returns that same `Traversable` type using the following code:

```
import scala.collection.TraversableLike

def dropN[E, T <: Traversable[E]]
(xs: T with TraversableLike[E, T], n: Int): T =
{
    xs.drop(n)
}

dropN(0 to 3, 1) // returns: Range 1 to 3
```

However if I try to make a similar function with recursion:

```
// basically finds the tail
def dropNR[E, T <: Traversable[E]]
(xs: T with TraversableLike[E, T]): T =
{
    if (xs.size > 1) dropNR[E,T](xs.drop(1)) else xs
}
```

I get the following message: `Type mismatch: expected T with TraversableLike[E, T], actual: T`.

Meanwhile a pure pass-through recursive method has no compile errors (but would obviously recurse forever)

```
def recurse[E, T <: Traversable[E]]
(xs: T with TraversableLike[E, T]): T =
{
    recurse[E,T](xs)
}
```

Why am I getting a `Type mismatch` when I use drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to use `CanBuildFrom`:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def dropR[E, D[E] <: Traversable[E]](xs: D[E])
(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[D[E], E, D[E]]): D[E] =
{
    if (xs.size > 1) dropR[E,D](xs.drop(1).to[D])  else xs.to[D]
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
dropR: [E, D[E] <: Traversable[E]](xs: D[E])(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[D[E],E,D[E]])D[E]

scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> dropR(l)
res0: List[Int] = List(3)

scala> dropR(l.toSeq)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = List(3)

scala> dropR(l.toSet)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(3)

scala> dropR(l.toBuffer)
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `xs.drop(1)` returns a `T`, not the mixed in `T with Traversable[E]` type you mix in to the original `xs`. In `recurse`, you're returning the unmodified collection, which is why it works.

I'm not sure why you need all those extra type parameters (perhaps I'm missing something), this should do:

```
def dropNR[E](xs: Traversable[E]): Traversable[E] = {
  if (xs.size > 1) dropNR[E](xs.drop(1)) else xs
}
```

Comment: The return type of this is `Traverable[E]`, is there any way to have the return type be the same type as the input type? So if I give it a `Seq[Int]` I want a `Seq[Int]` in return.

Comment: Maybe ^^ should be its own question but that is what I am going for

Comment: You can do that with a `CanBuildFrom` builder.

Comment: I have been working with those and trying to make it work, do you have any resources about what that would look like?

Comment: @evan058 Sorry, wasn't here to see your comment. But I see you got it yourself :)